# Как достать значение атрибута тега с помощью BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

У меня есть тег и мне надо достать у него текст атрибута data-peer-id

```
<a class="chatlist-chat" data-peer-id="404934257" href="#404934257">
```

как я могу реализовать на python с помощью BeautifulSoup4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt ='<a class="chatlist-chat" data-peer-id="404934257" href="#404934257">'
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'lxml')

print(soup.a['data-peer-id'])
```

вывод

```
404934257
```

"у меня таких очень много"

```
txt ='<a class="chatlist-chat" data-peer-id="404934257" href="#404934257">' \
     '<a class="chatlist-chat" data-peer-id="404934999" href="#404934999">'
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'lxml')

for x in soup.findAll('a'):
    print(x['data-peer-id'])

print([x['data-peer-id'] for x in soup.findAll('a')])
```

вывод

```
404934257
404934999
['404934257', '404934999']
```

Подробности и более крутые фишки в документаций https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ на прсторах интернета можно найти перевод на русский

Comment: Спасибо но вот у меня таких очень много

Comment: смотрите вот к примеру я спарсил с помощью метода findAll а потом написал функцию сбора айди из тега 
def get_id():
    for member in members:
        print(soup.member['data-peer-id']) 
и у меня вот ошибка 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
members = suop.findAll(a, class_ = "chatlist-chat")

Comment: Обращение к параметрам подобным (как описано у Вас) образом не самая лучшая практика. Есть метод `get()` который, в отличие от предложенного Вами варианта, не вызовет исключения при отсутствии параметра у тега, а даст возможность обработать этот кейс. Понятно, что Вы просто "по быстрому" набросали решение дающее общее понимание, но человек учится и будет считать такую практику нормальной. Кроме того используете название метода (`findAll`) оставленное для совместимости (в актуальной версии этот метод имеет название `find_all`)

Comment: @Namerek.  "Если что-то хочешь сделать хорошо, сделай это сам." Фердинанд Порше. А что вам помешало оформить ваш коментарий в виде ответа?

Comment: @СергейШашко, наличие достаточного ответа